# Tornado Server process the requests not average in multiprocess mode

Tags: python, tornado

I am using tornado server with version 5.1.1

Simple, I start the server like this:

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.bind(server_port, reuse_port=True)
process_num = 10
http_server.start(process_num)
```

But I found each a single process serving much of the request:

```
PID. PROCESS_REQUEST_NUM PERC
 519  329 0.462079
 501  53 0.0744382
 530  16 0.0224719
 478  28 0.0393258
 465  2 0.00280899
 470  24 0.0337079
 488  44 0.0617978
 509  216 0.303371
```

above,  the `pid=519` processing 46% of all reqeusts!

where is the problem?

Comment: Basically that depends on the scheduler. If there's not much load it might use the school group project algorithm (one does it all). Check how it looks under high load!

Answer (score 0):

When you use `reuse_port` with multiple processes, it's up to the kernel to distribute the requests among the processes, and it's not very smart in this case. It tends to balance out a little more at higher load (a process can only receive a request if it's idle when it comes in), but if it's important for you to balance the load more evenly across the processes you'll need to use an active load balancer like `nginx` or `haproxy`.